# Почему CSRF защита не даёт аутентифицироваться с первого раза?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

Делаю приложение. Сервер Java и UI React. Уже подключил CORS, но теперь не могу настроить CSRF защиту.

Конфигурация `Spring Security`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);

    http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

    http
        .rememberMe()
        .key("remember-secret-key")
        .rememberMeParameter("remember")
        .rememberMeCookieName("REMEMBER")
        .tokenValiditySeconds(REMEMBERED_SESSION_TIMEOUT)
        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository());

    http
        .formLogin()
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .successHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> {
            log.info("Principal {} logged on successfully", authentication.getName());
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        })
        .failureHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
            log.info("Login was failed");
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        });

    http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login") {
            @Override
            public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
                if (authException != null) {
                    response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
                }
            }
        });

    http
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Для аутентификации в React я разместил такой код:

```
const authRequester = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    withCredentials: true
});

export const profileAPI = {
    login(email, password, remember = false) {
        let bodyFormData = new FormData();
        bodyFormData.append('email', email);
        bodyFormData.append('password', password);
        bodyFormData.append('remember', String(remember));
        return authRequester.post('login', bodyFormData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'X-XSRF-TOKEN': getXSRFToken()
            }
        });
    }
}

const getXSRFToken = () => {
    return Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
}
```

Возникает любопытный эффект. Вообще, при одном нажатии на кнопку "Вход" делается два запроса, один OPTIONS, второй POST. Так вот именно POST возвращает 403 ошибку:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login | Request Method: OPTIONS | Status Code: 200
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login | Request Method: POST    | Status Code: 403
```

После первой попытки я нажимаю "Вход" ещё раз, и картина меняется. Мало того, что запросы OPTIONS и POST начинают идти в другом порядке, так ещё и аутентификация проходит успешно. После первого запроса все остальные запросы выглядят вот так:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login | Request Method: POST    | Status Code: 200
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login | Request Method: OPTIONS | Status Code: 200
```

Во-первых я не понимаю, а почему порядок запросов меняется? Разве смысл OPTIONS не в том, чтобы идти первым и "разведывать обстановку"? Во-вторых, что мне сделать, чтобы первый запрос проходил успешно?

#### UPD

Запрос Options (при первой аутентификации):

```
**General**
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response header**
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-xsrf-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 02 Apr 2021 14:36:29 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

**Request headers**
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-xsrf-token
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
```

Запрос POST (при первой аутентификации):

```
**General**
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login
Request Method: POST Status
Code: 403  Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0 Date: Fri, 02 Apr 2021 14:36:29 GMT Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=b09ad580-f93a-4a6e-9898-6b46099fef5b; Path=/
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

**Request headers**
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 353
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGaSAy1p6Mp8ixURe
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
X-XSRF-TOKEN: undefined
```

Comment: А после первой авторизации есть сделать запрос на ресурс с авторизацией, то не дает или дает?

Comment: @lampa ну вот я первый раз нажимаю "Вход", вылезает 403. Потом ещё раз нажимаю, всё проходит успешно. Тут момент такой, что после самого первого запроса мне не только 403 ошибка возвращается, но и кука XSRF-TOKEN. Поэтому, я так полагаю, следующие запросы и проходят.

Comment: Т.е. OPTIONS возвращает куку, а потом далее с ней выполняется POST?

Comment: @lampa нет, в том то и прикол, что OPTIONS сначала проходит и возвращает 200 код (но никаких кук). А потом пытается пройти POST, возвращает 403 и куку. Очень странное поведение.

Comment: Ну тогда логично, что первый OPTIONS не содержит в себе куки токена и POST запрос идет без токена и сервер возвращает 403, но видимо уже с токеном. И далее POST запрос уже идет с токеном. верно я понимаю?

Comment: @lampa да, так и есть. Я решил проблему, отключив защиту для ендпоинта `/login`. Сейчас всё работает корректно, но не понимаю, почему не работало раньше. Вообще, этот приём я увидел вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334171/spring-boot-post-request-with-csrf-token-produce-403-error , причём я увидел его там впервые.

Comment: Попробуйте просто предварительно получить куку с токеном до авторизации, если её не существует в куках

Comment: @lampa честно говоря с трудом представляю, как это сделать... Да, можно предварительный запрос делать, тогда будет ошибка падать 403, но и кука вернётся (как сейчас это происходит). Но мне кажется, это ещё более костыльно. Кстати, OPTIONS скорее всего вообще никакого отношения к CSRF-защите не имеет. Скорее это из-за CORS работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, отключив CSRF защиту для эндпоинта `/login`:

```
http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .ignoringAntMatchers("/login");
```

Вообще, это мне кажется странным, так как я совершенно случайно наткнулся в интернете на подобный приём, он не является общепринятым и широко известным. Возможно, в моём случае помогло только это, потому что я использовал одновременно CORS и CSRF. Не знаю. Если у кого-то будут более хорошие варианты, прошу высказаться. Но мою задачу этот приём пока что решает.